# Can you export an SSRS Subscription to an Azure File Share

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-storage

I created an Azure file share on a blob v1 storage account. I can connect to it from the OS on the report server, so I know the credentials are good, but when I configure a subscription via the reporting web site, it fails to connect, claiming "A log on error occurred when attempting to access the file share. The user account or password is not valid."

The azure account password is crazy long, so I'm wondering if it's having an issue storing it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the error if you don't offer the correct account and password (or even do not have an account) for file share. You could check the `subscription setting`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/subscription-settings-and-a-file-share-account-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017), and you need to make sure the account and password are all right. Also, you could store your azure account password in the tab.

[image]